# Redirect control panel access via .htaccess

Tags: craft3, redirect, htaccess

I have a website that is hosted on a subdomain, let's say: `https://subdomain.maindomain.nl`.

My craft content is in the `maindomain/public_html/subdomain/git-module` 
To make it work on the subdomain I added an htaccess file in the `maindomain/public_html/subdomain` with the following content:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.subdomain.nl$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.maindomain.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !git-module/web/
RewriteRule (.*) git-module/web/$1 [L]
```

For the front-end it is working. You can see everything on the `https://subdomain.maindomain.nl` url, but for the dashboard (which in this case is used for users as well, it still shows the whole url including `/git-module/web` like `https://subdomain.maindomain.nl/git-module/web/admin`.

My question is how I can delete this `/git-module/web` part of the url.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the subdomain symlink to you the /web folder. By doing so the normal public_html folder becomes the /web root folder for Craft CMS. This is way better than trying to redirect.